# Notification saying "Reassigned local variable" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

My string is getting underlined, with a notification saying `"Reassigned local variable"`. I have worked out that this happens any time that the string is modified, but I am not sure why this notification is coming up.

It doesn't appear do be causing any errors, and nothing is showing under the "problems" tab, so I'm not sure if it is something I should change or if I should just ignore it.

Below is a simplified version of the code.

```
Canvas canvas;
Paint p = new Paint();

String value = "a"; //'value' here becomes underlined

if(someCondition()) value += "bcdefghijklmnop"; //'value' here becomes underlined

canvas.drawText(value, 50, 50, p);
```

Comment: Whats the question? Do you want to avoid re-assigning the local variable or remove the notification?

Comment: @Tom The question is why the notification is coming up - what problem is it trying to indicate. I also had the same question.

Comment: I got this warning for loops when I was keeping track of some "previous" computed variable (i.e. from an earlier iteration of the loop). Strangely, the warning only appears in Java code and not Kotlin code. I assume this is because in Kotlin, a mutable local variable must be explicitly declared as `var` so it's clear it's intentional to be able to change it, but in Java it may indicate a mistake. But doesn't always indicate a mistake, so it's annoying to get a warning for this.

Comment: @AdamBurley Then you need to check your IDE and which conditions it warns about. Depending on the IDE you might be able to deactivate that check or reduce its severity.

Comment: @Tom Sure, but that would only apply for me and not all the other devs. Also, before pushing for deactivating a rule, I want to understand why it's there in the first place.

Comment: @AdamBurley Some devs prefer to not alter local variables to prevent unexpected values later in a method. Some other reasons are mentioned here: [Why would one mark local variables and method parameters as "final" in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/316352)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a notification, probably because sometimes reassigned local variables can cause problems for later operations. In your case it is totally legit to reassign, just be aware that it will create several new objects.

If you would like to prevent this, you could work with a `StringBuilder` here that you convert to a String whenever necessary, but this also creates a new `String` object, so if you don't use this in a loop usually it is not necessary to change anything (and for the string manipulation in a loop you probably will get a warning, a stronger sign for a potential problem in your code than this actual notification).